# Cantor's theorem via non-injectivity.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The usual proof of Cantor's theorem proceeds as follows. Let $X$ denote a set and consider a function $F : X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then we define $D \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ by writing $D = \{x \in X \mid x \notin F(x)\}$, observe that $D$ is not in the image of $F$, and thereby conclude that $F$ is non-surjective.

**Question.** Without using [CBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), is there a proof of Cantor's theorem that proceeds by considering a function $f : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow X,$ and finds distinct elements $C,D \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $f(C) = f(D)$? Thereby showing that $f$ is non-injective.

Comment: Yes, I believe this was asked before. Either here or on MO. Let me find links. **EDIT:** Here it is: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47458/cantors-argument-revisited and perhaps more relevant, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46970/proofs-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals/47022#47022