# Ways to prove that $|A|\neq |\mathcal P(A)|$ with CSB

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $\forall A$, $A$ is a set: $|A|\neq |\mathcal P(A)|$ with CSB (Cantor–Schroeder–Bernstein theorem).

I'm reading a proof that show that there's no surjection between $A\to \mathcal P(A)$.

They define a function $f$ such that $\forall a\in A, f(a)\in \mathcal P(A)$, and define: $B=\{x\in A| x\not\in f(x)\}\subseteq A$ so $B\in \mathcal P(A)$.

So $\forall a\in A, f(a)\neq B$ so, $B\not\in Im f$, so $Im f \neq \mathcal P(A)$ so $f$ isn't a surjection.

There's more, I can write down the rest but I don't quite understand the beginning, why define the function like that and isn't that a specific example? what does this $B$ have to do here?

Is there another way to do this? won't it be easier showing that there's no injection between $ \mathcal P(A)\to A$? (if $Dom f= \mathcal P(A)$).

Comment: what do you mean by CSB ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem or https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schr%C3%B6der_Theorem @idm

Comment: $x\notin f(x)$ has no sense.

Comment: @idm: note that for each $x\in A$, $f(x) \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. So $f(x)$ is a subset of $A$ and therefore, the statement $x \notin f(x)$ has meaning.

Comment: it's true, tks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895704/cantors-theorem-via-non-injectivity

Comment: @kuhaku: The map $f$ is not a "specific" example, but could be an arbitrary map from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$. That is: if $f:A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$, then by the definition of a map, we have $f(a) \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ for each $a \in A$. The idea of the proof is then as follows: Given an arbitrary map $f:A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$, they show that $f$ is not surjective. This is done by showing that the set $B$ is not in the image of $f$. In order to this, assume $B=f(a)$ for some $a \in A$. Then, either $a \in B$ or $a \notin B$. In both cases, you will be able to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give a quick answer to the first part.

We don't begin the proof of Cantor's theorem by defining a function. We don't define anything, that would defeat the purpose of showing that there is no surjection at all (what if there was, but it just happened to be different than the one defined?).

We begin by taking an arbitrary function $f\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$. What does it mean that a function has domain $A$ and codomain $\mathcal P(A)$? It means that for every $x\in A$, $f(x)\in\mathcal P(A)$. Namely, $f(x)\subseteq A$. Then we proceed to define $B_f=\{a\in A\mid a\notin f(a)\}$ and show that $B_f$ is not in the image of $f$, which means that $f$ is not surjective. The definition of $B_f$ depends on $f$, of course.

But what we show is that ***every*** function $f\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$ has a set $B_f$ which is not in $\operatorname{rng}(f)$. So we show that ***every*** function is not surjective.

---

You can, however, show that given $F\colon\mathcal P(A)\to A$, there is a pair of sets, $X,Y\in\mathcal P(A)$ which witness that $F$ is not injective.

Andres Caicedo gave [a very nice argument](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47022/7206). However, as his [follow up question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/47458/7206) shows, it's much harder to find a nice description of that pair $X,Y$. So proving there is no surjection remains the preferred approach.

Comment: I can't imagine how the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem could possibly be useful in a proof of $|A|\ne|\mathcal P(A)|$. Can you?

Comment: Well, in the same way that the usual Cantor's theorem is proved by contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Was it a joke?

Comment: Not a funny one. It's not particularly useful, just like contradiction is not useful in Cantor's theorem's proof.

Comment: How do we know that $B_f$ isn't empty?

Comment: @kuhaku: What difference does it make?

Comment: Ah even if it's empty then the empty set has no source.